# `tabular` - include column separator only between non-empty cells

Tags: tables, columns

I'm writing up a BNF definition using a custom environment, which is just a `tabular` with some specified column separators:

```
\begin{tabular}{r @{$\in$} c @{:=} l}
   ...
\end{tabular}
```

where the left column specifies the metavariable, the middle column is a human-readable name for the definition, and the right column is the BNF notation. For example, the naturals might look like

```
n & Naturals & 0 \mid S n
```

and be printed as

```
n \in Naturals := 0 | S n
```

#### The issue

My problem is this : some rows of this table will not have metavariables, because I don't have a need to refer to the thing they define in any other BNF rule. But if I leave out the metadata column, the `\in` still gets inserted (understandably), which doesn't look good.

```
\in Integers := n | -n
```

Some other rows will not have BNF definitions, because they are just metavariables. Similarly, the `:=` gets printed in these rows, which also looks bad.

```
i \in Indexes :=
```

When really I want

```
      Integers := n | -n
i \in Indexes
```

How can I make it so that the column separator will only be shown if there are values to separate between the two columns? I'm not averse to any extra packages.

Comment: Try replacing the empty metavariable with a custom command like, say `\nometa`, which you  define  as `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also want to do this at the end of the column (sometimes), leaving off the definition (and I'd like to not to have to add more formatting everywhere I do that).

Comment: I don't see exactly what should happen at the end of the column. Could you explain more, or give an example?

Comment: I've added more details and examples to the question. I should have said "at the end of the row", I think.

Comment: And the same command (perhaps with another name for semantic reasons) doesn't work in the last column?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: It seems that you want to typeset something like BNF. Would the existing packages [`syntax`](https://ctan.org/pkg/syntax-mdw) and [`simplebnf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/simplebnf) fit your need?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Is this an automated comment? In what way would those packages help answer my question?

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel I mean, there exists (although not perfect) packages in order to typeset BNF. Maybe they can help you. Or, if you would provide a more complete and detailed example of what style you want to get, people here can help you better.

Comment: Could you please explain what part of my question is unclear? I would like the `tabular` environment to not print the column separator if there isn't data in both cells either side of the separator. My question is not how to typeset BNF, that is just the example I am using.